# break not working with label inside a function error coming label not found

Tags: javascript, label, break

//break not working with label inside a function error coming label not found

```
var a = 10 ;
function myfn(){
  if(a===15){
    break stoplabel;
  }
  else{
    console.log(a);
    a++;
    stoplabel:myfn();
  }
}
myfn();
```

Comment: What you expect from your code ? Please share your expected output ?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `break stoplabel;` inside the `stoplabel:` code block.

For example:

```js
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];
var text = [];

list: {
    text.push(cars[0]);
    text.push(cars[1]);
    text.push(cars[2]);
    break list;
    text.push(cars[3]);
    text.push(cars[4]);
    text.push(cars[5]);
}


console.log(text);
```

You can change your code as below:

```js
var a = 10 ;
function myfn(){
  if(a===15){
    return;
  }
  else{
    console.log(a);
    a++;
    myfn();
  }
}
myfn();
```

Comment: so we cannot stop a recursive function call using break label

Comment: There is no point of using break label. You can call the function inside itself and stop the recursive loop just by calling `return;`.

Comment: help in this also pls function foo(i) {
  if (i < 0)
    return;
  console.log('begin:' + i);
  foo(i - 1);
  console.log('end:' + i);
}
foo(3);


Not able to understand how the console.log('end' + i) is working
can use link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_scope

Comment: `function foo(i) {if (i < 0) return; console.log('begin:' + i); foo(i - 1); console.log('end:' + i); } foo(3);` the functions are call in such order: `foo(3) -> foo(2) -> foo(1) -> foo(0)`. And the functions ends in the order of `foo(0) -> foo(1) -> foo(2) -> foo(3)`.